# Get ID of clicked object, selected by Name

Tags: javascript

I want to select a family of radio box elements of the name "clientName."  I can do so using:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("gender");
```

I want to create an event listener, such that if any of the radio buttons are clicked, it logs to the console the ID of the clicked element.  I imagine this involves using "this" and an onclick event.  So I tried the following, and it does not work:

```
x.addEventListener("click", myScript);
x.onclick=function(){console.log(this)};
```

However, this does not seem to do anything.  How would I achieve the desired result most elegantly?

[[EDIT: This is clearly not a duplicate of that post. This post does not have the jquery tag selected.  I am not interested in Jquery answers.]]

Comment: Hint: `.addEventListener()` and `.onclick` both apply to individual DOM elements, but `.getElementsByName()` returns a *list*...

Comment: I don't believe that .getElementsByName returns a list.  I believe it returns an object.

Comment: *"I believe it returns an object"* - And that object is definitely a list, even if only one element has the specified name. It's getElement**s**ByName - note the "s".

Comment: Check the second code snippet of the accepted answer. It doesn't use jQuery. You just need to replace the handler body with `console.log(this.id)`.